# vb.net if statement between range of numbers

Tags: vb.net

is there a way in vb.net that i can run an `if` statement to say if a variable starts with `07` then between `1-9`

i know i could do this using `substring` which would work but it would make the if statement rather large

```
number_called.Substring(0, 3) = "071" or number_called.Substring(0, 3) = "072"
```

and so on up to `079` but can i create a shorter `if` statement for the whole range?

Comment: Sounds like regex might be the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `String.StartsWith("07")` and check the last character of the `String` - it must be a number and not `0` like this:

```
If str.Length = 3 And str.StartsWith("07") And Char.IsNumber(str(2)) And str(2) <> "0" Then

End If
```

Answer (score 4):

This would do it

```
Private Function CheckNumber(myNumber As String) As Boolean
    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("^07[1-9]]")
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match(myNumber)
    Return match.Success
End Function
```

Just call `CheckNumber("071")` or `CheckNumber(number_called)`

Remember to import the references `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Updated Expression, thank you Veeke

Comment: MsgBox(CheckNumber("778071")) = true
Seems like the regex doesn't check if it starts with 07, just if it contains 07

Comment: New Regex("^07[1-9]")

Comment: @Veeke I tried ^07[1-9] but didn't work on regxr, I have updated with \b(07)[1-9] which works. Good catch - Need more coffee. EDIT: Need Multiline enabled........fml

Answer (score 2):

If you know that it will always start with 3 numbers you can parse it

```
Dim num = Int32.Parse(number_called.Substring(0, 3))
Dim Valid= num>69 and num<80
```

If you dont know if it will start with 3 numbers, surround it with a TryCatch

Answer (score 2):

Small correction on Malcor's post, which doesn't check if it begins with '07' (just if it contains '07'):

```
Private Function CheckNumber(myNumber As String) As Boolean
    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("^07[1-9]")
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match(myNumber)
    Return match.Success
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use StartsWith coupled with a Select Case if you are sure it is always a numeric string:

```
If number_called.StartsWith("07") Then
    Select Case CInt(number_called.SubString(2, 1))
    Case 1 to 9
         'it matched
    Case Else
         'it didn't match
    End Select
End If
```